# Flag if data frame contains same values as other data frame, across mutliple variables

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, one of which is a subset of the other. I want to visualize them (ggplot) indicating the subset of dataframes using a different color. I am therefore looking for a way to identify matches across data frames, flag the matches and use the flag as the col aesthetic.

Here is a short example:

```
#create two sample dataframes
df_full <- data.frame(type = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'), 
                      case = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2), 
                      val = c(3, 4, 7, 1, 5))

df_special <- data.frame(type = c('A', 'A', 'B'), 
                         case = c(1, 2, 1))

#print df for clarity                        
df_full
  type case val
1    A    1   3
2    A    2   4
3    B    1   7
4    B    2   1
5    A    2   5

df_special
  type case
1    A    1
2    A    2
3    B    1
```

What I want is the following:

```
  type case val special
1    A    1   3    TRUE
2    A    2   4    TRUE
3    B    1   7    TRUE
4    B    2   1   FALSE
5    A    2   5    TRUE
```

I can do this manually using `ifelse` conditions, but in cases where there are lots of potential matches this becomes laborious. I assume there is a simple way to to just check whether `type` and `case` match across df's (similar to a join function) and then flag if they would join. I can't seem to word the search correctly to find anything.

`dplyr` solutions would be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a join

```
library(dplyr)
df_full %>% 
    left_join(df_special %>% 
                 mutate(special = TRUE))%>% 
    mutate(special = replace_na(special, FALSE))
type case val special
1    A    1   3    TRUE
2    A    2   4    TRUE
3    B    1   7    TRUE
4    B    2   1   FALSE
5    A    2   5    TRUE
```

---

Or another option is `%in%` on the `paste`d columns 'type', 'case'

```
library(stringr)
df_full %>% 
      mutate(special =  str_c(type, case) %in% 
                   str_c(df_special$type, df_special$case))
```

Comment: Ah of course, make the flag in the special dataframe and then just join. Much appreciated.